# SQL LEFT JOIN same Table with non-exist record?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Anyway to do a LEFT JOIN for sql when one of the data record is empty (or non exist). If it is non exist, return a dummy data like 0, possible?

This is the query for the LEFT JOIN, result is empty.

```
-- QUERY --
SELECT DISTINCT(timestamp), td1.value as Apple, td2.value as Orange, td3.value as Lemon
FROM TableData as td
    LEFT JOIN TableData as td1 ON td1.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts
    LEFT JOIN TableData as td2 ON td2.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts
    LEFT JOIN TableData as td3 ON td3.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts
WHERE
    td.attribute_id IN (16,17,18) AND
    td1.attribute_id=16 AND
    td2.attribute_id=17 AND 
    td3.attribute_id=18
ORDER BY timestamp;

-- Finally GET --
timestamp     | Apple   | Orange | Lemon |
--------------+---------+--------+-------+
<-- Empty Row -->
```

Below is the sample relation of the table.

```
-- TableData --
attribute_id  | value     | timestamp  |
--------------+-----------+------------+
17            | 100       | 1618822794 |
17            | 100       | 1618822861 |
16            | 50        | 1618822794 |
16            | 50        | 1618822861 |

-- TableAttribute --
id            | name     |
--------------+----------+
16            | Apple    |
17            | Orange   |
18            | Lemon    |

-- Expected Result --
timestamp     | Apple   | Orange | Lemon |
--------------+---------+--------+-------+
1618822794    | 50      | 100    | 0     |
1618822861    | 50      | 100    | 0     |
```

Comment: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Comment: Unless there is a 16, a 17 and an 18 row, as coded your query will return an empty row.  Your code requires (at least) one of each to be present.

Comment: so there is no way to join them together even 18 is not there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to pivot the values.
For that, I think conditional aggregation is simpler:

```
SELECT td.timestamp,
       MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 16) as Apple, 
       MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 17) as Orange, 
       MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 18) as Lemon
FROM TableData td
WHERE td.attribute_id IN (16, 17, 18) 
GROUP BY td.timestamp
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Example with `coalesce()`:

```
SELECT td.timestamp,
       COALESCE(MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 16), 0) as Apple, 
       COALESCE(MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 17), 0) as Orange, 
       COALESCE(MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 18), 0) as Lemon
```

Comment: So if I want to make sure the value is not null, I do the like this? 

`CASE
 WHEN
  CAST(MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 17) as DECIMAL) ISNULL 
 THEN 0
  ELSE CAST(MAX(td.value) FILTER (WHERE attribute_id = 17) as DECIMAL) END as Orange`

Comment: @Sola . . . You would use `coalesce()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT td.ztimestamp
        , td1.value as Apple, td2.value as Orange, td3.value as Lemon
FROM TableData as td
    LEFT JOIN TableData as td1 ON td1.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts AND td1.attribute_id=16 
    LEFT JOIN TableData as td2 ON td2.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts AND td2.attribute_id=17 
    LEFT JOIN TableData as td3 ON td3.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts AND td3.attribute_id=18
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM TableData x
        WHERE x.snapshot_ts = td.snapshot_ts
        AND x.attribute_id IN (16,17,18)
        )
ORDER BY td.ztimestamp;
```

---

ALSO: `timestamp` is a keyword. Better not use it as a column name.